# Как узнать какой поток выводит текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Подскажите как узнать какой поток в данный момент выводит каждую цифру.

```py
import threading

def writer(x, event_for_wait, event_for_set):
    for i in range(10):
        event_for_wait.wait()
        event_for_wait.clear()
        print (x)
        event_for_set.set()


e1 = threading.Event()
e2 = threading.Event()
e3 = threading.Event()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(0, e1, e2))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(1, e2, e3))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(2, e3, e1))


t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

e1.set() 

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

Comment: В `writer` добавьте `print(threading.current_thread())`

Comment: @gil9red помогло, пасиб. закиньте в ответ, я отмечу выполненным

Comment: @DDDsss: Мульти-поточность в Python-е весьма интересная. Почитайте про GIL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы узнать в каком потоке сейчас выполняется код можно вызвать [threading.current_thread()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread).

В `writer` добавьте:

```
print(threading.current_thread())
```